# How to add custom CSS span into a text input box ( like Stack Overflow )?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make the same feature of Stack Overflow's Tags selector ( the one below ). I have read [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), which [Stack Overflow heavily inspired from](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/102531/143844). But the main difference of Chosen and the Stack Overflow's one is that Stack Overflow allows users to type and auto-complete the tag, while Chosen can only select from a list.

How to change the code of Chosen's multiple select demo to make similar thing as Stack Overflow's Tags selector ?

Here is the code from Chosen's multiple select demo:

```
    <div>
      <em>Into This</em>        
      <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chzn-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
        <option value=""></option> 
        <option value="United States">United States</option> 
        <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>  
      </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to change? The style and add an "x" button?

Comment: @Chen read? "But the main difference of Chosen and the Stack Overflow's one is that Stack Overflow allows users to type and auto-complete the tag, while Chosen can only select from a list."

Comment: If i type in the multiple select field the list gets filtered... try it out. This is pretty much, what you want, don't you?

Comment: I don't see the difference - SO has a huge list of tags, and autocomplete refers to them. Are you talking about new tags as well?

Comment: @Chen I think the OP simply wants to type with autocomplete instead of manually choosing from a list.

Comment: @Christoph SO also doesn't autocomplete for you, it gives you a list of appropriate results. They're prettier, but fundementally the same as Chosen's. So I'm not sure exactly what he wants

Comment: @Chen well, that's what the OP meant I guess. Not exactly "Auto-complete" but rather "suggests" if you want to be nit-picky.

Comment: Yes @Christoph is right. Also from Chosen's demo, I cannot create new "tags" by typing; I have to select from the existing list.